# SlowCheetah not transforming root XML element with multiple attributes

Tags: slowcheetah

I'm trying to add a `SlowCheetah` release transformation for my `NLog.config` file. The `NLog.Release.config` looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog 
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" 
    autoReload="true" 
    throwExceptions="true" 
    internalLogLevel="Off" 
    internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" 
    xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" 
    xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <extensions>
        <!--<add assembly="NLog.Targets.RabbitMQ" />-->
    </extensions>
    <targets async="true">
        <!--<target xsi:type="Console" name="console" error="false" layout="${time:format=HH:mm:ss} ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=ToString}"/>-->
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console"/>-->
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Here, I'm trying to replace the whole contents of the file using `xdt:Transform="Replace"` on the root element. However, I'm getting the following error on build with `Visual Studio 2015`:

> C:\Projects\WebSite\Properties\SlowCheetah\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets(184,5):
>   error : Could not write Destination file: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

I did a few experiments, and found out that this error goes away if I remove all the attributes from the root `nlog` element (`autoReload`, `throwExceptions`, etc). But I need to replace the whole file, including all those attributes.

Why can't `SlowCheetah` perform this transformation? How can I make it transform the whole file, including all the attributes on the root element?

Comment: Looks like a limitation in Microsoft XDT framework. Only allows a single attribute on the root-element: https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/153